# Spring JTA transaction jboss

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss, transactions

I'm new with Spring and I'm trying to configure it by using the transaction manager of jboss. Indeed, i receive this exception:

*Caused by: org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaPlatformInaccessibleException: Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate*

This is my config.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/mydb"/>
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ufirst" />

</bean>
<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:jboss/TransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransactionName" value="java:jboss/UserTransaction" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
```

And this is my repository, that return the error:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

public class RoleRepositoryimpl implements RoleRepository {

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RoleRepositoryJpa.class);

@PersistenceContext(unitName="entityManagerFactory")
private EntityManager em;

@Transactional
public Role find(String role){
    logger.info("in repository");
    return em.find(Role.class, role);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: First of all you should use a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` instead of what you have now. You should either use `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />` which detects what server you are on. Or configure it manually, don't do both.

Comment: I have changed the entity manager factory as your advice, but the result is the same. Instead, the tag '<tx:jta-transaction-manager />' was still present in my xml configuration file

Comment: You should also configure the correct `JtaPlatform`. what is in your `persistence.xml`?

Comment: Thank you Deinum, by adding this it works!